# Could not start AVD in avd manager for flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I am new to flutter mobile app development .When i configure my virtual device ,and run it.I am getting 'Could not start AVD' pop up.Not able to run my virtual device.any idea what am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using linux? If so, I solved it by allowing permission to /dev/kvm device.

You need to first `sudo apt install qemu-kvm`

Then add the current user by running `sudo chown <Replace with username> /dev/kvm`

You can check your username by running `echo $USER`